# How to simulate a voltage sag/swell condition using Three-Phase Programmable Voltage Source?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have been trying to simulate power quality disturbances such as voltage sag, swell, harmonics, etc. I thought of using the Three-Phase Programmable Voltage Source block of SimPowerSystems in Simulink, but all I get is a zig-zag signal even though the output should be sinusoidal. Can anyone tell what could have gone wrong in the parameters of the said block-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zig-zag signal is typical for a too big simulation step. Adjust `max step size` in your solver settings.